# SQL Server accent sensitive update issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation, diacritics

Below is the data i have in two tables, the collation on both the colums is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Table1:

```
Ccode   Cname

1       Hawai?i Kai

2       Hawi
```

Table2:

```
Ccode    Correct_CCname 

 1        Hawaiʻi Kai

 2        Hāwī
```

Update Statement:

```
UPDATE T1 
SET T1.Cname  = T2.Correct_CCname
 FROM Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 
 ON T1.Ccode = T2.Ccode
```

I am trying to do an update, not sure what collation i should use to retain the accents for the alphabets (Hāwī) and the left single quote (ʻ).
When i run the update statement am not able to pass across the accent of the alphabets or the single quote. Please advice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What data type are the `Cname` and `Correct_CCname` columns, `nvarchar`? That's the more important thing. If they are not, change them to `nvarchar`. I can't reproduce any problem using `nvarchar`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8c4b3/1)

Comment: Ok thank you for the update, will give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you @stickybit that did the trick.